# How to find records from table A, which are not present in table B?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use a SQL Server 2008 database.

I have two tables with columns like these:

`Table A`:

```
request_id|order_id|e-mail
100       |2567    |jack@abc.com
100       |4784    |jack@abc.com
450       |2578    |lisa@abc.com
450       |8432    |lisa@abc.com
600       |9032    |john@abc.com
600       |9033    |john@abc.com
```

`Table B` has also `id` and `order_no` columns and many others columns:

`Table B`:

```
request_id|order_id|e-mail
100       |2563    |oscar@abc.com
300       |4784    |peter@abc.com
600       |9032    |john@abc.com
650       |2578    |bob@abc.com
850       |8432    |alice@abc.com
```

As you can see, a given `request_id` in table A can occur more than once (see 100 & 450 records)

I need to find all records from table A, which are not present in table B by `order_id`, but have equal `request_id` column values.

For above example I expect something like this:

`Output`:

```
request_id|order_id|e-mail
100       |2567    |jack@abc.com
100       |4784    |jack@abc.com
450       |2578    |lisa@abc.com
450       |8432    |lisa@abc.com
600       |9033    |john@abc.com
```

As you can see above records from table A are not present in table B. This criteria is only satisfied with record where `order_id=600`

I created the sketch of T-SQL query:

```
select 
    D.request_id, D.order_id 
from 
    table A AS D 
where 
    D.request_id = 600 
    and D.order_id not in (select M.order_id 
                           from table B AS M 
                           where M.request_id = 600)
```

Unfortunately I don't have idea how to transform my query for all `request_id`. The first think is to use while loop over all `request_id` from table A, but it seems not smart in SQL world.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
SELECT a.*
FROM      table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.request_id = b.request_id
                   AND a.order_id   = b.order_id
WHERE b.request_id IS NULL
```

Check here - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7dec7/1/0)

Comment: Thank you. Currently I can't test it in real example, but it seems that it works! One question: Do I change last WHERE condition to "WHERE b.order_id IS NULL"? I see that it also works and it seems more comfortable for me, because I'd like to find all non-matching request_id :)

Comment: Since, both columns (`request_id` and `order_id`) are used in `JOIN` clause, you don't need it. It's the same thing.

Comment: Maybe I'm mis-understanding the requirement, but I thought the OP was saying that he wants all cases where there is a record in table B that matches table A on request_id but NOT on order_id. The above query will list records from table A which have no match in table B on either request_id or order_id.

Comment: This doesn't match the OPs problem statement: all rows in A with a match in B on request id, but no match on BOTH request and order id.

Comment: @NicholasCarey That's what I thought he meant at first too. But then look at his expected output. I think he needs to clarify what he means by "have equal request_id column values". Equal to what?

Answer (score 2):

```
select request_id, order_id from table_a
except
select request_id, order_id from table_b
```

EDIT: this does not work in MS SQL:

If you want the email addresses as well:

```
select request_id, order_id, email from table_a
where (request_id, order_id) not in (
    select request_id, order_id from table_b
)
```

Comment: In MS SQL, you need to use `EXCEPT` instead of `minus`.  The syntax is otherwise identical.  The second method I don't believe works in T-SQL.  You could also do `table_a LEFT JOIN table_b` on primary keys, followed by `WHERE table_b.<primary_key> IS NULL`.

Comment: @BaconBits I don't understand the clue of your second solution. What do you mean by primary_key in this case? Is it request_id? IMHO in LEFT OUTER JOIN I only can match tables with one condition, so how I can match by request_id and order_id? Thanks

Comment: @Viper AgentSQL's answer is what I was thinking of.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the EXCEPT. Learn something new every day ;)

Comment: @BaconBits Thank you for your help. Now I understand your approach I think

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT  request_id, order_id,e-mail
  FROM  table_a
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT  request_id, order_id,e-mail
  FROM  table_b
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "but have equal request_id column values". Equal to what?

If you simply want all the records in table_a that do not have a record in table_b with matching request_id and order_id, then:

```
select a.request_id, a.order_id
from table_a a
where not exists (select * from table_b b where b.request_id=a.request_id 
  and b.order_id=a.order_id)
```

Comment: This fails the O.P.s problem statement as well.

Comment: As I said at the beginning of my post here, I think the OP needs to clarify his problem statement. I believe the above query will give what the OP lists as his expected output given the stated inputs.

Answer (score -1):

The Original Poster's problem statement was (and I quote):

> I need to find all records from table A,
>   which are not present in table B by order_id ,
>   but have equal request_id column values.

The thing about SQL is that is has strong mathematical underpinnings from

- set theory, and
- the predicate calculus

Thus, the O.P's problem statement can be simply restated in standard SQL, pretty much as-is:

```
select *                                    -- select all rows
from A a                                    -- from table A 
where exists (                              -- * that have at least one matching
        select *                            --   row in B with the same request ID
        from B b                            --
        where b.request_id = a.request_id   --
      )                                     --
  and not exists (                          -- * but have no matching row in B
        select *                            --   with the same
        from B b                            --   request AND order IDs
        where b.request_id = a.request_id   --
          and b.order_id   = a.order_id     --
      )                                     --
```

Easy!

Comment: Do return values match with expected output? I don't think so. Look at his `OUTPUT`.